# Migrating tables from the main database to the test_db to perform tests, and deleting the test DB after (fastapi and pytest)

Tags: python, sqlite, pytest, fastapi

I started writing the Test module following the official documentation and came up with the following code:

```
from ..app.user.model import User
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from .temp_app import app

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from app.server.database import get_db, Base

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./test.db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
TestingSessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

def override_get_db():
    try:
        db = TestingSessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db

client = TestClient(app)

#perform tests imported from different modules

Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
#attempt to delete the database after the tests are over
```

the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL` is supposed to perform the tests in test.db and the `override_get_db` method is supposed to get test.db rather than the main database.

When I run the tests with `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL` pointing to the main SQL database, the tests run fine, but with my code I get:

> app\test\test_db.py (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users

which indicates that the tables from my database have not migrated to test.db.

I couldn't find any info on this in the [official documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-database/), and so I am a little confused if I did something wrong, or there just needs to be some code which will migrate the tables to test.db.

Can someone please help me understand this, and run tests with all the tables in the test database?

Also, the test.db file is not deleted after pytest is done running tests, so maybe I don't understand how `Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)` works.

Thank you for your time.

Edit:
Logs after importing all the models and setting `echo=True`

```
2022-02-04 17:43:37,691 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2022-02-04 17:43:37,691 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT users.id AS users_id, users."mobileNo" AS "users_mobileNo", users.email AS users_email, users."fullName" AS "users_fullName", users.role AS users_role, users."referralCode" AS "users_referralCode", users.status AS users_status
FROM users
WHERE users."mobileNo" = ? OR users.email = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
2022-02-04 17:43:37,691 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 9.304s ago] ('1234567890', 'johndoe@gmail.com', 1, 0)
(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users
[SQL: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users."mobileNo" AS "users_mobileNo", users.email AS users_email, users."fullName" AS "users_fullName", users.role AS users_role, users."referralCode" AS "users_referralCode", users.status AS users_status
FROM users
WHERE users."mobileNo" = ? OR users.email = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: ('1234567890', 'johndoe@gmail.com', 1, 0)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
2022-02-04 17:43:37,692 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured log call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:log.py:117 BEGIN (implicit)
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:log.py:117 SELECT users.id AS users_id, users."mobileNo" AS "users_mobileNo", users.email AS users_email, users."fullName" AS "users_fullName", users.role AS users_role, users."referralCode" AS "users_referralCode", users.status AS users_status
FROM users
WHERE users."mobileNo" = ? OR users.email = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:log.py:117 [cached since 9.304s ago] ('1234567890', 'johndoe@gmail.com', 1, 0)
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:log.py:117 ROLLBACK
============================================================================================================= warnings summary =============================================================================================================
app\testOptions\model.py:4
  C:\Users\shrid\OneDrive\Documents\backend\app\testOptions\model.py:4: PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class 'TestOptions' because it has a __init__ constructor (from: app/test/test_db.py)
    class TestOptions(Base):
 
app\testResponse\model.py:9
  C:\Users\shrid\OneDrive\Documents\backend\app\testResponse\model.py:9: PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class 'TestResult' because it has a __init__ constructor (from: app/test/test_db.py)
    class TestResult(Base):
 
app\testResponse\model.py:25
  C:\Users\shrid\OneDrive\Documents\backend\app\testResponse\model.py:25: PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class 'TestQuestions' because it has a __init__ constructor (from: app/test/test_db.py)
    class TestQuestions(Base):
 
-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
========================================================================================================= short test summary info ==========================================================================================================
FAILED app/test/test_db.py::test_create_user - AssertionError: {"detail":"Something went wrong!"}
```

Edit 2: User Model:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    mobileNo = Column(String, index=True, nullable=False, default="")
    email = Column(String, index=True, nullable=False, default="")
    fullName = Column(String, nullable=False, default="")
    role = Column(String, default='user')
    referralCode = Column(String, default='1234567890')
    status = Column(String, default='active')
```

Comment: Are you importing models before create_all() method?

Comment: @sudden_appearance Well, I haven't written any code to import models. In the main application, I just put `__tablename__ = "<name>"` while defining the models and the tables were executed using MySQL workbench. Can you please elaborate a little on how I may import the models for the database?

Comment: Your models are inherited from a `Base` class. When you are creating them somewhere else they are not imported and thus are not binded to Base in any way. So Base.metadata.create_all() does not know anything about your models. You can configure your engine with `echo=True` and will see that there is no SQL transactions that are creating database. Try importing models on top of file or in `__init__.py` of a module where Base class is created

Comment: @sudden_appearance Do you mean `from app.models import User` at the top of the file? doing just that didn't work. Do I need to register the models somewhere?

Comment: No, importing should be enough

Comment: @sudden_appearance but I am still getting the same error `app\test\test_db.py (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users`

Comment: Can you add `echo=True` to your `create_engine(...)` method, remove test.db and restart with updating logs to this post?. It must generate sql with creating database and show it. Also please provide a file structure for better understanding

Comment: @sudden_appearance I have added the log, please have a look

Comment: Can you provide your User model code? At least class definition and __tablename__.  Base does not know about user model and thus does not create a user table

Comment: @sudden_appearance I have added the User model

Comment: I guess you should commit your changes after `Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)`

Comment: @stuck I tried running it with `TestingSessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=True, autoflush=False, bind=engine)` instead of `autocommit=False`, that should automatically commit all changes right? Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

i can not give you a "sure" answer unless I see the whole module where you set your ORM models, but reading what you wrote, I think that if you import `Base` from your models' module ( which is the same you use in all your app ), the `Base` will have an object called metadata ( `Base.metadata`), which will include all your models, so when you call `create_all()` , it will see the models you defined and it will be created.
make an import like this: 
`from my_app_path.models.main_module_that_has_all_models import Base` 
in case you have your models spread all over the app structure, you should have a module that imports them all, because it will be a pain to deal with ORM models if you have them spread here and there.